# How to set Firebase Push Notifications properly for iOS? (Followed documentation already, details below)

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

So, here is the case: I'm trying to set up push notifications with Firebase using the APNs Auth Key (the new method for APN authentication from Apple), I followed the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client?authuser=0), and the only way I can receive a notification sent from the Firebase Console is when the app is installed with the production entitlement (using Ad hoc distribution profile through [TestFairy](https://testfairy.com) in this case).

Whenever I sent a notification through the firebase API (using Postman or `curl`) this is what I get:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 8099318512563041133,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1506438549617006%7e86ee7a7e86ee7a"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I just receive the notification in the Ad hoc distributed app.

Using this script http://thrysoee.dk/apns/ I am able to send notifications to development successfully.

To this point, I don't know what I am missing, I even tried in a blank project, so, have anyone faced anything similar that could give me some light here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I will leave the question open, but I already "manage" to solve the issue. All I did was simply uninstall the app from the iPhone and install it again and now everything is working smoothly (development and production).

What was happening? I surely have no idea, but uninstall and install again did the trick for me.